# How to check if element is present inside a nested data structure

Tags: groovy

```
test_list = [Record(topic = nr-dev-01, partition = 0, offset = 10, serialized key size = 3, serialized value size = 873, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = oregon_ht01, value = {"push_status": "SUCCESS", "push_summary": {"_index": "date_io_kl", "_package": "_zip", "id": "tUz1", "version": 1, "found": "true", "_source": {"Manual": {"Preamble": {"Product_name": {"@value": "Flight manual 101"}, "Version": {"@value": "1.0.0"}, "License_info": {"@value": "LICENSED COPY - February 03 2023"}}}}}}]
```

I'm trying to find if 'key' is present as part of test_list if so, get its value, ideally (oregon_ht01)

But it fails saying

groovy tst.groovy

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
tst.groovy: 1: expecting ')', found 'key' @ line 1, column 133.
   e = 1684410534479, serialized key size =
```

Code Snippet

```
def keyToFind = 'oregon_ht01'

if (test_list.contains(keyToFind)) {
    println("Key $keyToFind found in messages")
} else {
    println("Key $keyToFind not found in messages")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the `test_list` contains only the objects of Record type, and all  `Record`'s properties are public, the code would look like:

```
if( test_list.any{ it.key == keyToFind } ) {}
```

Comment: While testing it reports following error ..
`tst.groovy: 3: expecting ')', found 'key' @ line 3, column 91.
    = 0, offset = 10, serialized key size =`

Comment: `[Record(topic = nr-dev-01, part` this thing is not compilable at all